# envoy proxy validation context match OID (x509)?

Tags: envoyproxy

Team : similar to this below information, is there a way to check "OID" X509 number ?
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/securing#use-mutual-tls-mtls-to-enforce-client-certificate-authentication
for example, in nginx, we have this way using [subject alternative](https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples#reading-subject-alternative-from-client-certificate-httpcertssubject_alternative)

```
import x509 from 'x509.js';

function san(r) {
    var pem_cert = r.variables.ssl_client_raw_cert;
    if (!pem_cert) {
        return '{"error": "no client certificate"}';
    }

    var cert = x509.parse_pem_cert(pem_cert);

    // subjectAltName oid 2.5.29.17
    return JSON.stringify(x509.get_oid_value(cert, "2.5.29.17")[0]);
}

export default {san};
```